# IBM HS20 Blade server rebooting due to NMI Error

Tags: boot, ibm, bladecenter

I have an HS20 Blade which is mounted inside a BladeCenter H Console. When I first boot the machine, it displays the following error:

> See the System Error Log. Re-booting due to unexpected NMI at 0012:7AA4.

(See screenshot below for more information)
[image]

Then the machine reboots before allowing me to enter the bios configuration or diagnostic utilities to investigate further. I have several questions about this to begin isolating the problem.

1. Is this NMI error related to the blade itself or the bladecenter it is plugged into?
2. Does this type of error indicate a hardware problem or a software/firmware/bios configuration issue?
3. What is the best way to troubleshoot/isolate this issue?

Any help is appreciated to get things moving in the right direction.